# Dynamic 301 .htaccess Redirect/Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website with a forum and here is the current rewrite rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/?forum/?(.*)$ /forum.php [L]
```

Now, because of that I have urls indexed by Google like:

```
www.domain.com/abc/forum/rest-of-url  
www.domain.com/defg/forum/rest-of-url   
www.domain.com/something-else/forum/rest-of-url
```

and all links are showing the same page, which should be access only as:

```
www.domain.com/forum/rest-of-url
```

without any words(abc, defg, etc) between the domain/ and /forum/

Basically anything like this link:

```
www.domain.com/abc/forum/rest-of-url
```

should be 301 redirect to:

```
www.domain.com/forum/rest-of-url
```

I tried changing the rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /forum/?(.*)$ /forum.php [L]
```

But then I get lots of 404 errors in Google Webmaster tools for all previously indexed URLs, so I think there is a work around with 301 redirect, but I haven't figured out how to avoid going in a loop.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect any /foo/forum/index to /forum/index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(forum/[^/]+/?)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Sorry, index part is dinamic: www.domain.com/something-else/forum/index can be www.domain.com/forum/someting-else